# Should I unit test concurrency?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, black-box-testing

I have a few methods that are impacted by concurrency. Specifically "Rush" (a.k.a Race) conditions. Should I unit test them or integrate/black-box test them?

I think that setting up a unit test might be a rather difficult task, but also is integration test...

Comment: @rene race conditions, I guess

Comment: Also I don't think it's possible to test that explicitly. Maybe some integration tests that will sporadically fail

Comment: Relevant question over at programmers SE: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/196105/testing-multi-threaded-race-conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've found this article and its quite instructive about my question: https://testing.googleblog.com/2014/02/minimizing-unreproducible-bugs.html

Answer (score 4):

Unit tests must be deterministic, so concurrency doesn't belong there. (I keep my unit tests completely synchronous.)

Go for integration tests to sniff out race conditions — but be prepared for false positives. In other words, the tests passing is no proof that you don't have a race condition. But a failure will alert you to something you need to fix.